# Sort number part of a string?

Tags: javascript, sorting, typescript

We have a bunch of `SomeItems` which have a field `someId` which is in the format (simplified / replaced with dummies): 

`abc.def1.<someNumber>`

I have an array of `SomeItems` and have been sorting it like this:

```
let rows = someItems.sort((lhs, rhs) => lhs.someId > rhs.someId)
```

This pretty much just sorts it alphabetically, so this means that the order comes out a little weird:

```
abc.def1.1
abc.def1.1234
abc.def1.1235
abc.def1.2
abc.def1.234
```

I instead want it to be numerically sorted - like 1, 2, 234, 1234, etc.

What's a clean way to do this?

Comment: Just filter out the parts you don't want (with regex or something else) when comparing in the comparator function.

Comment: Also note that the comparator should return a number, not a boolean.

Comment: Btw, notice that `(lhs, rhs) => lhs.someId > rhs.someId` [is not a working comparison function for `sort`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with options.

```js
var array = ['abc.def1.1', 'abc.def1.1234', 'abc.def1.1235', 'abc.def1.2', 'abc.def1.234'];

array.sort(function (a,b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' });
});

console.log(array);
```